# Stripe card number field not showing since upgrade to 6.6

Tags: payment-processor, stripe

The block to enter credit card info is not showing up on my registration form so when submitted it does not go to Stripe...

Civi 5.36.1
Drupal 7.80

Answer (score 2):

I removed the "US" country code from the Stripe settings and the credit card block appeared. Not sure why but at least I have a working registration form.